# How a frontend container can communicate with an API container on the same EC2 instance using a load balancer

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, vuejs2

I have my Ec2 instance running a multiple container application. My frontend is running Vue js and my backend is running. Net core 5. I have nginx reverse proxied with my frontend docker file. On my local machine, the system is working fine. The containers are communicating using the machine ports. The problem I have now is I have the ssl certificate on a load balancer for my ec2 instance. I can reach my frontend fine, but it can't communicate with my backend as it is making an http request. I have tried creating another application load balancer for my API port to use https on another port but that is also not working. Is there a solution for this without getting another ssl certificate for the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the certificate from ACM, the certificate will be terminated by the ALB, then the ALB will send http traffic to your EC2 instance.

Please make your frontend use https request, and if you setup right, the ALB will terminate the ssl, and your backend will receive the http request without install ssl certificate in the server.

Comment: This is working for my frontend traffic. But for my api, it isn't. As the system is using another port. I can't really access it although the container is running.

Comment: Do you use different domains for Frontend and Backend? If you do, you can create a traffic rules in ALB. Base on the host header, you can forward traffic to target group which points to your backend port. ALB by default can only listen on port 80 and 443, and the traffic ports are defined by target group

Comment: I actually don't. But maybe I should do that. I thought the alb can listen on any port that you set. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer can help you, please mark it as accepted. If you need further guide, I can help you